# Leave only one priority notification class in markup Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

There is an icon with a notification dot above it, which is painted for the color of the notification.

Notifications are of three types: success - green, warning - orange, error - red.
Notifications are colored by priority, green low - red highest.

For example, if there is a warning message, the bell will always be colored orange, even if the success message comes after. If there is an error message, then the bell will always be red, even if a success or warning message comes after it.

In this code, the bell is colored by priority, but if all three different notifications comes,  all classes are visible in the markup but not that one that has priority:

```
<button>
  <span
    class="Icon name_notification"
    :class="iconClasses"
  ></span>
</button>

 computed: {    
  iconClasses() {
  const {
    notifications,
  } = this;
  return {
    indication: !!notifications.length,
    'has-success': notifications.findIndex(({options}) => options.type === 'success') !== -1,
    'has-warning': notifications.findIndex(({options}) => options.type === 'warning') !== -1,
    'has-error': notifications.findIndex(({options}) => options.type === 'error') !== -1,
  };
 },
}
```

The problem is that in html markup, you can see the developer console, all classes are rendered if 2, 3 different notifications comes.The markup should only indicate the color class that the bell is painted, i.e. highest priority class

An example of what is output in code:

`<span class="Icon name_notification indication has-success has-warning has-error"></span>`

An example of how it should be:

`<span class="Icon name_notification indication has-error"></span>`

I tried the following options, but no class is displayed in markup and the bell is not colored

```
 iconClasses() {
      const {
        notifications,
      } = this;
      const topPriority = ['has-error', 'has-warning', 'has-success'].find(type => notifications.some(({options}) => options.type === type));
      return {
        indication: !!notifications.length,
        topPriority
      }
    },
```

```
iconClasses() {
      const {
        notifications,
      } = this;
      const indication = !!notifications.length;
      const className = [{indication}];
      if(indication) {
        const topPriority = ['has-error', 'has-warning', 'has-success'].find(type => notifications.some(({options}) => options.type === type));
        className.push(topPriority);
      }
      return className
    },
```

Comment: How is `iconClasses` being applied? Is it just through `<span :class=iconClasses">` and the object gets automatically resolved? Or are you doing something to resolve the object you're returning from `iconClasses()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are returing an object and resolving it to be used in the template. But I hope even if the format I'm using to return is not exactly what you need, that you will see the logic in it.

You could run a chain of conditional returns.
If there is an error, return the error type.
If not, and there is a warning, return the warning type.
If not, and there is a success, return the success type.
If not, return default.

If there is no "default" state, you could get rid of the success conditional and make it the default, and obviously, you could do better with the `indication: !!notifications.length` to not calculate it every time, but I wasn't sure what that was meant to be, so I didn't try to do much with it.

```
iconClasses() {
  const {
    notifications,
  } = this;
  if (notifications.findIndex(({options}) => options.type === 'error') !== -1) {
    return `${!!notifications.length ? 'indication' : ''} has-error`
  }
  if (notifications.findIndex(({options}) => options.type === 'warning') !== -1) {
    return `${!!notifications.length ? 'indication' : ''} has-warning`
  }
  if (notifications.findIndex(({options}) => options.type === 'success') !== -1) {
    return `${!!notifications.length ? 'indication' : ''} has-success`
  }

  return `${!!notifications.length ? 'indication' : ''}`
 }
```

Hope it helps, and let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Thank you so much, everything works. Great clear solution